# Why is memcpy to on-stack memory much faster than to on-heap memory?

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I first create a file as follows:

```
struct event_data
{
    uint32_t data_1;
    uint32_t data_2;
    uint32_t data_3;
    uint32_t data_4;
    uint32_t data_5;
    uint32_t data_6;
    uint32_t data_7;
    uint32_t data_8;
};

FILE* fp = fopen("C:\\test.bin", "w+b");
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
{
    event_data data;
    fwrite(&data, sizeof(event_data), 1, fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

After that I tried to use boost's memory mapped file to read data from the file:

```
clock_t start = clock();

event_data stack_buffer;
event_data* heap_buffer = new event_data();

for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
{
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file mmap("C:\\test.bin", boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readonly);
    const char* data = mmap.const_data();
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        const event_data* evt = reinterpret_cast<const event_data*>(data) + i;
        // Use memcpy to copy data to buffer, either (1) or (2)
        // memcpy(&stack_buffer, evt, sizeof(event_data)); <== (1)
        // memcpy(heap_buffer, evt, sizeof(event_data)); <== (2)
    }
}

clock_t end = clock();

printf("%f sec\n", (double) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

If I use (1), it prints out ~ '0.56 sec'. If I use (2), it prints out ~ '26.6 sec'. Why are results so different?

Comment: C or C++? They are separate languages

Comment: I created Win32 Console project in VS2008. It should be C++, I guess

Comment: @AnttiHaapala could you please explain?

Comment: Did you tried to run many times? Exchange this 2 lines?

Comment: I am pretty sure compiler decides that with buffer on stack, the compiled code copies the buffer just once, not those 100000 times. And thus this is not even a C question, but C++.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I moved `event_data stack_buffer;` into the inner loop. The results don't change.

Comment: It does not matter, the compiler knows the variable is useless.

Comment: No, it cannot be  because of TLB misses, this is a 2 decade difference, and the target area would be always in TLB.

Comment: Try to do something with the memcopied variables, maybe the stack version is optimized out and the external one not as the compiler cant see if other modules do something with the data

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen Tried putting `stack_buffer.data_1 += 1; stack_buffer.data_6 = 0;` in the inner loop. There is nothing different.

Comment: Did you also see that difference when your code is compiled without any optimisation s?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Measuring unoptimized code is pointless.

Comment: @n.m. why ? It could help to find an answer to the question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Turned off optimizations, now I got the same time consumed by 2 cases. So compiler's optimizations would make the difference.

Comment: @duong_dajgja OK, that's interesting, I think i'ts worth to have a look at the assembly code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No. It can help find an answer to a different question, namely, is unoptimized compiler performance is different or same in the two cases. But it's a pointless question to ask. Who cares? Why should we believe the compiler at two different optimization settings would produce output files that are even remotely similar? If you want to know how an optimizing compiler works, you need to study an optimizing compiler.

Comment: @n.m. actually the OP's answer to my question pointed me into the direction of your answer. OK, you found the answer before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written two functions:

```
extern int moo1 [100];
extern int moo2 [100];


void foo1 ()
{
    memcpy(moo2, moo1, sizeof(moo1));
    moo2[2] = moo2[77] + moo2[14];
}

void foo2 ()
{
    int moo3[100];

    memcpy(moo3, moo1, sizeof(moo1));
    moo3[2] = moo3[77] + moo3[14];
}
```

Here's what gcc compiles them to:

**foo1**

```
_Z4foo1v:
.LFB5:
    pushq   %rdi
    .seh_pushreg    %rdi
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg    %rsi
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    .refptr.moo1(%rip), %rsi
    movq    .refptr.moo2(%rip), %rax
    movq    (%rsi), %rdx
    leaq    8(%rax), %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    andq    $-8, %rdi
    movq    %rdx, (%rax)
    movq    392(%rsi), %rdx
    subq    %rdi, %rcx
    subq    %rcx, %rsi
    addl    $400, %ecx
    shrl    $3, %ecx
    movq    %rdx, 392(%rax)
    rep movsq
    movl    56(%rax), %edx
    addl    308(%rax), %edx
    movl    %edx, 8(%rax)
    popq    %rsi
    popq    %rdi
    ret
```

**foo2**

```
_Z4foo2v:
.LFB6:
    .seh_endprologue
    ret
```

Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: That means compilers are smart enough to 'ignore' unnecessary works, right?

Comment: @duong_dajgja Yes. And you should not measure perfomance of isolated snippets to choose which one to use. Measure real working code perfomance and use the best. I is no uncommon to see approach A to perform better than B in synthetic tests, but lose to it in real code.